# Can I use $(this) to affect another selector?

Tags: jquery

My dilemma is I have the id soundclip that I want users to click but change the class of a div inside of .container

```
$( ".container #soundclip" ).bind({
          click: function() {
          $('.container .audioNavOff').removeClass('audioNavOff');
          $('.container $(this) div').addClass('audioNavOn');
          },
      });
<div class="container">
      <div class="audioNavOff">HD AUDIO</div><div class="audioContainer1"><a href="#"><img id="soundclip" src="assets/img/hd-audio-off.jpg" alt="" class="center"/></a></div>
      <div class="audioNavOff">DIGITAL</div><div class="audioContainer2"><a href="#"><img id="soundclip" src="assets/img/digital-audio-off.jpg" alt="" class="center"/></a></div>
      <div class="audioNavOff">ANALOG</div><div class="audioContainer3"><a href="#"><img id="soundclip" src="assets/img/analog-audio-off.jpg" alt="" class="center"/></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: .container $(this) div') this is not valid

Comment: You can use selectors with other elements **$('SELECTOR', this)**. But its very hard, you must better structurize your HTML.

Comment: `Id` must be unique!!! Use `class` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings().eq(0).addClass('audioNavOn');
```

Should work. It adds the class to the elements that's two levels above the clicked image element, and then selects its first sibling, which is your div.

UPDATE

I'd **strongly** suggest you restructure your HTML a bit: use a container for each of the three options. You can even wrap them in your audioOff class, like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="audioNavOff">HD AUDIO
    <div class="audioContainer1">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="soundclip center" src="assets/img/hd-audio-off.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="audioNavOff">DIGITAL
    <div class="audioContainer2">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="soundclip center" src="assets/img/digital-audio-off.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="audioNavOff">ANALOG
    <div class="audioContainer3">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="soundclip center" src="assets/img/analog-audio-off.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can combine the audioNavOff and audioContainers into one div:

```
<div class="audioNavOff audioContainer1">
```

or even use IDs (this is where they would be used properly):

```
<div class="audioNavOff" id="audioContainer1">
```

Whichever way you choose, it will make your life much easier to keep them grouped, the code will be easier to maintain, and your final addClass call should be (in case of the big nested example I wrote above):

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('audioNavOn'); // $(this).parents().eq(2) is fine too
```

And btw. you shouldn't have duplicate IDs on your page, use classes instead. (see my example)

Comment: I tried your solution but it is changing all div class="audioNavOff" vs. just the one that had its child image clicked . I added a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WLAC4/

Comment: That's your code. :) I haven't touched that and it's one of the things you need to fix. You need to remove the off class only on the div that will get the on class... so you can add `.removeClass('audioNavOff')' to that chain I gave you. Btw. your fiddle shows a mix of two ideas I gave you, let me fix it.

Comment: This works as I would expect. But, if I wanted to remove the previous .audioNavOn that I previously clicked on and add it to the existing one I am clicking on. Therefore, only one can be active. Would toggleClass() be an option or does that just do an off/on

Comment: toggleClass is a good idea for your app, but it won't work right away as it just turns the class on and off. If you wish to keep it the way you have it now, you can simply remove the on class like this: `$('.audioNavOn').removeClass('audioNavOn');`

Comment: but wouldn't it remove the class and then add it again with      $(this).parent().parent().prev().removeClass('audioNavOff').addClass('audioNavOn');

Comment: No, that one removes the off class and adds the on class... The code I gave you above removes all the on class on all divs that have it and it should be ran before the toggle code.